# Umlauts in filename not stored correctly in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, utf-8, wildfly

I have a file upload in my web application. Users can upload a file via the file-model directive. I save the filedata in a JSON and send it to an endpoint on my Wildfly server. There I persist the file data in a MySQL database. When printing the filename in the console(client-side) there are no umlauts errors in the filename. Also before persisting the filename and printing the filename in Eclipse console I see no error. However, in the database the filename is saved wrong (e.g. testä.jpg becomes testa?.jpg). Also when printing a string with that filename **before sending the data to the server** in the view it is also displayed as testa?.jpg. I included `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head of the seed page already.
The field `filename` in the database is encoded as UTF-8 and has collation utf8_general_ci. The database/server setup and JVM options don't seem to be the problem since I can save umlauts correctly if they are typed in a textfield.

Here is how file data is retrieved:

```
$scope.submit = function () {

    $scope.employeePhoto = {};
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    r = new FileReader();

    r.onloadend = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
        $scope.employeePhoto.photoContent = uint8ArrayToArray(new Uint8Array(data));
        $scope.employeePhoto.fileName = $scope.UploadFile.name;
    }
    // http request to the endpoint
}
```

The problem might be that the filename is already stored wrong in the `$scope.UploadFile.name` variable but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your column in MySQL is defined as VARCHAR(n) CHARSET utf8.  From your explanation, that should be the only problem I can think of.

Also, check if your select and insert statement is using N for selecting the column. Like this:

```
SELECT N'some text';
```

Comment: It is defined as VARCHAR(255) with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Oh! Please check the select and insert statements then. Please see my updated comment above.

Comment: The problem seems to be lying when reading the filename already. When I print the filename in my view the umlaut is displayed wrong already before even persisting the data.

Comment: If you use ajax to post data to the server in JSON format then you could try add -->    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"   to your ajax code.  OR  this -->  beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        },

Comment: I'm using angulars `$http` method

Comment: That's strange. What IDE are you using? Try saving your javascripts, html, etc. with UTF 8 encoding. If you're using Visual Studio, go to File -> Advance Save Options --> Encoding "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"

Comment: Try changing $scope.employeePhoto.fileName = $scope.UploadFile.name; to 

$scope.employeePhoto.fileName = 'UTF-8\'\'' + $scope.UploadFile.name;

Comment: What's your Server side language? Is it Java?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java. However, I believe the issue happens before even sending the data to the server. I tried writing  `$scope.UploadFile.name` to the HTML page and it's displayed wrong there as well. I think it has something to do with the angular directive for file uploads `<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" file-model="UploadFile">`

Comment: That seems to be issue with your JavaScript or HTML not correctly saved with UTF-8 encoding. Try some other IDE and see if it helps.  May be Sublimt Text.  Also, I found other places where people have solved it on server side like this in Java:
new String (filename.getBytes ("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

Comment: The interesting thing is that I use the same JS file for another function namely to rename an Employee. When I change its name via a input text and put an umlaut in its name there is absolutely no issue. So it can't be the file's encoding, right?

Comment: That's true. I don't know what else could be the issue if any of the above suggestions aren't working for you. Sorry, I am out of suggestions.  Please do let me know if you find a solution. It would be interesting to know, in case I fall in the same issue.